# Are there any ad networks that serve ads over SSL?

Tags: advertising, https

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Ad service that supports ssl (secure publishing)](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/17080/ad-service-that-supports-ssl-secure-publishing)

I have recently enabled SSL on my site, now my google ads cause some browsers to complain about unsecured content (because Google Ads are served over http). Are there any ad networks that serve ads over SSL?

Comment: Are you specifically looking only for ad networks? Asking because while Adsense does function as a network in many ways(eg. drop in some code and just take the ads that come), it also has ad *management* features. If you're looking to replace it completely, that changes the context a bit.

Comment: @Su', I'm just looking for some service to serve ads over SSL