# Ad service that supports ssl (secure publishing)

Tags: https, security-certificate, google-adsense

Is there an add service like adsense that supports SSL ads?  I wish to put ads on a secured (https) pages but Google Adsense doesn't support it.  I know Adbrite works for text based SSL ads but I would prefer image based ads.

Answer (score 2):

[BuySellAds](http://www.buysellads.com) offers SSL ad code, but it's not exactly an AdSense-type network. If you have a high quality site with decent traffic you should have no trouble selling ads directly to advertisers through them, though. There are enough advertisers actively checking out properties available in their directory.

Answer (score 0):

BuySellAds does not support SSL at this time.  I spent several hours setting up an account and configuring ad code on my site based on the previous answer.  Your site must also go through an approval process.  When their placement scripts failed to load under SSL, I opened a support ticket and found out they do not support SSL.  This wasted quite a few hours of my time - after already wasting hours not knowing Adsense did not support SSL.

The best solution I have found so far is this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15139070/592473

I setup a DoubleClick for Publishers Small Businesses account yesterday.  It was very easy since it automatically links to your Adsense account.  My unsold ads are configured to fall back to Adsense, and the code they provide checks for SSL.

That being said, it has not been 100% perfectly SSL.  It has only been one day so I am still monitoring, but occasionally a non-SSL ad gets through.  Also, while I was hoping for image ads, most of them are coming through as text versions.  I am hoping this will improve over time.

I hope this helps someone else since I have been looking for a way to place a few ads on my SSL website.

Comment: I know this is an old post, but for new readers Adsense supports ssl - https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/10528?hl=en